# How to execute a Selenium Java test using batch file?

Tags: selenium, java, batch-file

I have created a batch file containing Java file locations :

"% C:/location..."

Now , when I double click this file, it opens up eclipse with this java class inside.

What I want is that this file also should get executed by clicking the batch file, and after that, the rest of the classes in this package should get executed.

How can I do this?

Comment: why are you opening "eclipse "? without opening also you can execute your test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you try to run the java file and not the compiled code. Try exporting your project as an executable .jar via eclipse and run this via "java -jar FileName.jar". Regarding the second part of your question though, I´ve got no idea what you were trying to say.